Impossible to debug javascript freeze with devTools
Using devTools and adding logs everywhere didn't help me debug a particular page.
I am working on a web component framework, and without going into the details or the way things work, I have my Chrome-based browser freezing during around 30 sec to 1 minute when I perform a particular action, and I can't find any way to see where it is stuck. The same action in Firefox is immediate and has no consequence.
I have put a debugger just before the crash happens but it didn't help.
Do anyone know a better way or wanna have a look ?
https://cp.bbn.io/computed.php
Just click the checkbox (it should change the number of the last entry of the list - called Chiara - at the bottom of the scroll).
Thanks!
EDIT: Can anyone confirm they have the same bug please?

It's working just fine for me (in Chrome). The value is being changed and the debugger is pausing naturally with no crash. And it's logging everything that it's supposed to. The only thing that took some time was the list generation though... I mean, the page loads with empty list and takes about 2-3s to render the list and the checkbox... But the checkbox function is not freezing my browser so far after rendered...

Maybe the problem is being caused by some extension specifically installed in your Chrome...

Thanks, I have this same error with Vivaldi and Chrome, both locally and on the URL I sent. I have no extension installed, I don't understand how it could come only from my environment

Tuns just fine in Vivaldi

On a second look, I managed to reproduce the problem. I was tweaking some options on DevTools then found out...
It looks like when DevTools is registering network data (you can stop that), when you click the checkbox it freezes the DevTools for a while. Mine took about 10s to 30s to unfreeze the DevTools that was stopping the page scripts...
But if you stop the DevTools from registering network data then it return to work like normal.
So, I think it's related to the DevTools frameworks shared between some browsers... Maybe Chromium...
The only solution I see through here is turning that feature off then.

When you say "registering network", you mean to have the option "preserve log" on?
In both ways the problem went on, and same without devtools on.
Now after your message I closed all my other apps, and tried again with Chrome, and this time no problem, with or without devltools/preserve logs. I reopened Vivaldi, and he same problem occured, I have the latest version and I even upgraded yesterday and the problem was on before and after.
It's maybe not my code, but hard to say now...

My Chrome is in another language, but the free translation of the specific tweak is "Stop recording network data" and the shortcut for tweaking it is CTRL+E.

No, still the same with or without it
